# Show all the tables content

Tags: postgresql

Supposing I have these tables:

- Table_1
- Table_2
- Table_3

How can I perform a `SELECT` but for all the tables in a certain database ?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*for all the tables in a certain database*"?

Comment: Do all these tables have the same columns? If not, what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Please show what you have already tried.